# What is the best approach to log all DB queries and view them when needed?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, monitoring

Is there an efficient way to log all DB queries in Staging and Production without having a big impact on performance?

Is there a good tool(free or paid) that does it?

The DB Engines I am working with are: MySql and MongoDB

Note: I know how to write all the DB queries into a log file. This solution is too slow for production and I am curious to know if there is a better way to store the logs and then easily find/browse them.

Comment: You can use [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) for MongoDB - for querying logs, setting up a cluster quickly (for example, in dev), etc.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL you can get query templates and the associated counters from performance_schema. You can use PMM's query analytics to analyze this data.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the "general log".  Beware -- it can chew up disk fast.

The output is all the queries being performed, and it is in a text file.

For chasing "slow" queries, use the slowlog.

(Both are built into MySQL.)